# Omitting " starting to"

Tags: word-choice, present-continuous

I read this sentence in a story: "I’m starting to get worried about him.”
If I write this sentence as : "I am getting worried about him." Would it change the meaning, anyway?

Comment: If you want to use "starting to..." I would phrase it as "I am starting to worry about him."

Comment: Thanks @Weather Vane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. "Starting to" puts more emphasis on the fact that the subject "I" wasn't really worried before. That's why you hear exchanges like:

> "Are you getting worried about him?" asked Tom's mother.
>
> "Starting to," answered Tom's father.

It's the difference between "I'm becoming worried" and "I'm starting to become worried." Using the present progressive "am starting" followed by an infinitive verb gives the infinitive verb a futurate sense, thus casting that action into the future, a future that because of "starting" is an immediate future, one that is exactly on the cusp of the present, one that begins with this very moment's passing, thus emphasizing that one was not getting worried before or one dismissed any earlier worries that may have cropped up as not worrisome or truly worrying.

Comment: Thanks @Benjamin Harman